# Why is Breath or Wind a better translation choice then Spirit?

Tags: pneumatology

**["Spirit" occurs 505 times in 456 verses in the KJV](http://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=spirit&t=KJV#s=s_primary_0_1).** The English word is translated from the Hebrew *ruach* and the Greek *pnuema*. Both of these words can also mean "breath" or "wind."

All three uses can be seen in the Flood account.

> [Genesis 6:3](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Gen&c=6&v=3&t=KJV#s=6003) And the LORD said, My **spirit** shall not always strive with man, for that he also is flesh: yet his days shall be an hundred and twenty years.
>
> [Genesis 7:15](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Gen&c=7&v=15&t=KJV#s=7015) And they went in unto Noah into the ark, two and two of all flesh, wherein is the **breath** of life.
>
> [Genesis 8:1](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Gen&c=8&v=1&t=KJV#s=8001) And God remembered Noah, and every living thing, and all the cattle that was with him in the ark: and God made a **wind** to pass over the earth, and the waters asswaged;

In the New Testament, two of the uses can be seen in the same verse of John's Gospel.

> John 3:8 The **wind** bloweth where it listeth, and thou hearest the sound thereof, but canst not tell whence it cometh, and whither it goeth: so is every one that is born of the **Spirit.**

However, in the New Testament, the word "breath" is never translated from *pneuma* but instead from the word *pnoe* ([Acts 2:2](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Act&c=2&v=2&t=KJV#s=1020002); [17:25](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Act&c=17&v=25&t=KJV#s=1035025)).

In what situations is "breath" or "wind" a better translation choice then "spirit"? What is the reason that these words meaning "[wind](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H7307&t=KJV)" and "[breath](http://biblehub.com/greek/4151.htm)" get the English word "spirit" as a final definition?

Comment: Please limit this to a particular passage. Adequate contextual analysis of 505 instances in three different languages is not feasible in this format.

Comment: To the close voters, although the OP mentions that there are 505 instances, I think the question is only looking for a rule of thumb, not an analysis of all instances.

Comment: I agree it's much better after Frank Luke's edit, although it seems like the "rule of thumb" is just "look at the context."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be more about a general language issue rather than a specific question arising from a particular text.

Comment: For all the uses of the word Spirit, only so many specific words have been used. If instead of referencing the outcome and more specifically the group of words. It makes for a more feasible format. However in doing so, like Jack wanting reference to a specific text, I lose scope. My opinion is that the words only gained the definition as "Spirit" because of the translations themselves. So it is a language issue. So how can I limit scope while maintaining contextual analysis? I though Frank, fixed that problem. How it is off topic, I do not understand. Please help me understand. Thanks Love.

Comment: Each translation decision requires an analysis of the local context. The question as is still has 6 different instances referenced in two different languages. If there is a particular passage where you don't understand the translation decision, ask that.

Answer (score 1):

This is like asking why λογος or λογον means "reason" or "mind" in one place and "word" in another, or even "treatise" as in Acts 1:1.  It would come out absurd to pick one definition from the semantic range and always use it, so as to translate Acts 1:1 "The former *mind* I composed..." rather than "The former *treatise* I composed..."  One might could get away with "The former *word* I composed..." if the word "word" had the same semantic range in English that it does in Greek, but it doesn't today.

*Because its obvious from the sentence in question.*

For example in Genesis 7:15 "...wherein is the *wind* of life" would make no sense, while either *spirit* or *breath* would.

In Genesis 6:3 saying either "My *breath* shall not always strive with man" or "My *wind* shall not always strive with man" would make no sense, while "My *spirit* shall not always strive with man" does.

Now, in John 3:8, it seems quite likely that he is giving an analogy comparing the spirit to the wind (due to the idea of *blowing*), not just making a pronouncement on the spirit, which is why το πνευμα is translated "the wind" at the beginning but εκ του πνευματος is translated "of the Spirit" at the end.

Common sense and context are the rule here.