# Does 1 John 3:8-9 teach that a person can be entirely free from sin and sinning?

Tags: 1-john, sin

In the Scriptures we read:

> He that committeth sin is of the devil; for the devil sinneth from the beginning. For this purpose the Son of God was manifested, that he might destroy the works of the devil. Whosoever is born of God doth not commit sin; for his seed remaineth in him: and he cannot sin, because he is born of God (1 John 3:8-9).

Christians do not sin, the Scriptural text quoted above is understood as saying. Now if you employ the text in corroboration of your view that Christians do not sin, are you seeking to create a vision
of what I paint below?:

"Christians are beings advanced beyond the possibility of breaking the
Law of God. A Christian is literally and absolutely perfect: he has
100% freedom from sin - whether in deed, or in word, or in thought - so
that he can run the gamut of earthly existence without even harbouring
an evil thought or losing his tongue for a second to inglorious
words."

Comment: I'm not sure why there are any close votes on this question, which is clear, answerable, and obviously arises from the text quoted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should we understand "he cannot sin" in 1 John 3:9?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13584/how-should-we-understand-he-cannot-sin-in-1-john-39)

Answer (score 3):

Such an idea of absolute sinless perfection is obviously impossible - only Jesus achieved this.  1 John 1:8, 10 states this emphatically.

> If we claim to be without sin, we deceive ourselves and the truth is
>   not in us. … If we claim we have not sinned, we make him out to be a
>   liar and his word is not in us.

1 John 3:8, 9 is discussing intentional, willful sin.  Only in heaven or the New Earth (depending on your eschatology) will be completely sin free.

As imperfect sinners, we should recall two verses earlier in the same letter of 1 John 1:9, 2:1;

> If we confess our sins, he is faithful and just and will forgive us
>   our sins and purify us from all unrighteousness. … My dear children, I
>   write this to you so that you will not sin. But if anybody does sin,
>   we have an advocate with the Father--Jesus Christ, the Righteous One.