# Is Hebrews 6:4-8 saying that Isaiah 27:4-5 does not apply to Christians who fall away or that it does?

Tags: contradiction, hebrews, soteriology

> [Hebrews 6:4-8 NASB20] (4) For it is impossible, in the case of those who have once been enlightened and have tasted of the heavenly gift and have been made partakers of the Holy Spirit, (5) and have tasted the good word of God and the powers of the age to come, (6) and [then] have fallen away, to restore them again to repentance, since they again crucify to themselves the Son of God and put Him to open shame. (7) For ground that drinks the rain which often falls on it and produces vegetation useful to those for whose sake it is also tilled, receives a blessing from God; (8) but if it yields thorns and thistles, it is worthless and close to being cursed, and it ends up being burned.

> [Isaiah 27:4-5 NLT] (4) My anger will be gone. If I find briers and thorns growing, I will attack them; I will burn them up-- (5) unless they turn to me for help. Let them make peace with me; yes, let them make peace with me."

Can those who have fallen away return and make peace with God?

Comment: Luke 18:27 “what is impossible for man is possible with God”. Thus, it is too difficult a task for man to lead a backslider back to the straight and narrow, but if this person is one of the chosen few God himself will step in and put things straight.

Answer (score 1):

*“Then who can be saved?” 26 And looking at them, Jesus said to them, “With people this is impossible, but with God all things are possible.” – Mat 19:25-26*

The proposition that man could, of himself, be saved was never a viable possibility. That said, the message of Hebrews (6:1-8) is stern yet not entirely without hope.

- But if it yields thorns and thistles, it is worthless and close to being cursed, and it ends up being burned. – Heb 6:8

The ground is only “close to being” cursed. The implication is that only if it persists in yielding thorns and thistles, does it “ends up being burned.” This little opening for hope aligns with the theme that God forestalls judgment, giving us time to repent and reconcile with him.

> But do not let this one fact escape your notice, beloved, that with
> the Lord one day is like a thousand years, and a thousand years like
> one day. 9 The Lord is not slow about His promise, as some count
> slowness, but is patient toward you, not willing for any to perish,
> but for all to come to repentance. – 2 Pet 3:8-9

We find this theme echoed in the parables as well:

> And He began telling this parable: “A man had a fig tree which had
> been planted in his vineyard; and he came looking for fruit on it and
> did not find any. 7 And he said to the vineyard-keeper, ‘Look! For
> three years I have come looking for fruit on this fig tree without
> finding any. Cut it down! Why does it even use up the ground?’ 8 But
> he answered and said to him, ‘Sir, leave it alone for this year too,
> until I dig around it and put in fertilizer; 9 and if it bears fruit
> next year, fine; but if not, cut it down.’” – Lk 13:6-9
>
> The slaves said to him, ‘Do you want us, then, to go and gather them
> up?’ 29 But he said, ‘No; while you are gathering up the weeds, you
> may uproot the wheat with them. 30 Allow both to grow together until
> the harvest; and at the time of the harvest I will say to the reapers,
> “First gather up the weeds and bind them in bundles to burn them; but
> gather the wheat into my barn.”” – Mt 13:28-30

Regarding the OP’s question, the message of God’s patience and mercy in calling us to repentance is beautifully expressed in the first part of Isaiah 27 (2-6 ).

- Or let him rely on My protection,
  Let him make peace with Me,
  Let him make peace with Me.
  – Is 27:5

The end of the passage, however, paints a bleak picture of what happens if we persist to ignore God’s offer of peace. In contrast to the fruitful vineyard of God, the alternative is a desolate city of man’s own making (Is 27:10-11). Here, as in the Hebrews text, the end involves burning.

- For the fortified city is isolated, A homestead deserted and abandoned like the desert; There the calf will graze, And there it will lie down and feed on its branches. When its limbs are dry, they are broken off; Women come and make a fire with them, – Is 27:10-11

Answer (score 0):

Hebrews is not written to the body of Christ which is separate from the nation of Israel. It was written to "Hebrews" which is to "the Circumcision." Salvation for the Circumcision requires they stay faithful, or endure to the end, which means the end of their own life, or up to the Lord's return for Israel to the earth. (Matthew 24:13)

There were two churches or congregations during the Pentecostal Administration covered by the of Acts. The Circumcision, of whom Peter and the 12 were party to, is reached in the first 12 chapters (within Palestine). Proselytes in the land are also reached (The Ethiopian eunuch and Cornelius are examples).

The body of Christ began in Acts 13:1-2 when Paul and Barnabas were severed from the Circumcision to go into the Gentiles. This new mission required a different gospel, the Gospel of the Uncircumcision. Also called "The Gospel of God, this gospel is recorded in the first 4 chapters of Romans by Paul, the apostle to the Gentiles.

The Circumcision church leadership was usurped by James, the brother of Jesus who was not an apostle. He was a Judaizer and held fast to the Law of Moses. Eventually, the Circumcision church worked to prevent Paul from witnessing to the Gentiles and tried to kill him.

These are those spoken of in the Hebrew scriptures you quote. They were not members of the body of Christ, but of the Jewish congregation. God had promised He would bring in Gentiles as proselytes, but He never promised equality between Jews and Gentiles.

In Acts 28 the Circumcision church, Israel, was held in abeyance due to their rejection of the risen Christ. At that time Ephesians was written, declaring a new humanity in which Jews and Gentiles are fully equal.

Salvation in the body of Christ is permanent because of justification and reconciliation (Romans 3 Romans 5, I Corinthians 5). Our salvation is totally by God's grace through the faith of Jesus Christ (Ephesians 2:8-10). We do not have to "endure unto the end" to be saved, but are sealed the moment we believe with the Holy Spirit unto the day of redemption (Christ's return to meet the church which is his body, in the air.)

Comment: You said: “The Circumcision church leadership was usurped by James, the brother of Jesus who was not an apostle. He was a Judaizer and held fast to the Law of Moses.”  Where is your source for that assertion?  Did Philo or some other ancient source confirm that?  Also, the Epistle to the Hebrews could have been written to Christians in general, we read: “Therefore, holy brothers and sisters, partakers of a heavenly calling, consider the Apostle and High Priest of our confession: Jesus;”
‭‭Hebrews‬ ‭3:1‬ ‭- Holy brethren can be gentiles too, see: (Galatians 3:28-29).

Comment: The body of Christ doesn't have a "High Priest" but a Mediator, "the man Christ Jesus who gave His life a ransom for all..." The body of Christ has no priests at all -- apostles prophets evangelists pastors and teachers. To Israel, Christ is High Priest, to the body of Christ he is Mediator and Head of His body.

Follow James the brother of Jesus in the gospels. He thought Jesus was insane along with his other brothers. James was not chosen as one of the 12 and was not nominated  to replace Judas. How did he rise to power over the 12 in Jerusalem? Only by compromise with the Sanhedrin.

Comment: You don’t have any proper sources for your assertions, therefore they are to be rejected as mere speculation.  Jesus is both our High Priest & Mediator.  Paul said Jesus was the mediator between God & Man.  (1 Tim 2:5). He didn’t say Jesus was the mediator between God & Gentiles.  Jesus saves both Jews & Gentiles:  “There is neither Jew nor Greek, there is neither slave nor free, there is neither male nor female – for all of you are one in Christ Jesus. And if you belong to Christ, then you are Abraham’s descendants, heirs according to the promise.”
‭‭Galatians‬ ‭3:28-29‬

Comment: The research behind what I wrote is in my book "Between the Gospels: The Chronicle of Israel's Apostacy and Gentile Belief" and is much to involved to present here. It's available free if you want it (pdf). You make the common mistakes most of Christendom makes in not realizing Israel is not the church but is still separate. Only those of the "remnant according to this present time" are coming into the body of Christ. The rest are blinded until we are taken up. Then the Jewish church will be reinstated and Jews and Gentiles will not be equal as seen in the verses about the Millennium.

Comment: Regarding Jesus as "High Priest" you will notice in Paul's writings there are no priests in the body of Christ. That was Israel's system. He is our Mediator according to I Timothy. Paul calls him our Lord, the Head of the church which is his body, but never calls him our "high priest." Paul doesn't use many terms applied to Israel but people haven't noticed and made the distinctions.

Comment: @Christan Doulos
It is amazing what opens up out to see the difference between the gospel of the uncircumsion  and the gospel of the circumcision.  What does it mean that Paul acted in a priestly service on behalf of the Gentiles?  Rom. 15:16 to be a minister of Christ Jesus to the Gentiles in the priestly service of the gospel of God, so that the Gentiles might become an offering acceptable to God, sanctified by the Holy Spirit.  Any insight  as to what that means would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Good question Sherrie -- to answer that from the Word we have to know WHEN Paul wrote his various epistles. From Acts 13:2 to Acts 19:20 (around there), Paul served in his priestly function, but that function was deprecated when God announced "The Conciliation" in Romans 5 and II Corinthians 5 (both written around the time of Acts 19:20). He served as priest because Gentiles were aliens from the commonwealth of Israel -- they had to come through Israel to receive spiritual blessings. Paul served in that capacity. At that time, Jews and Gentiles were NOT equal. Not until Ephesians was written.

Comment: So the body of Christ began when Paul and Barnabas were "severed" to preach "the gospel of God" to the Gentiles... but it wasn't until Israel fully rejected the testimony of the Holy Spirit in the book of Acts that their Kingdom was held in abeyance. That's when God revealed the mystery, or secret, about the current administration during which Jews and Gentiles are equal. Israel had to apostatize before that man-to-man (Jew to Gentile) reconciliation could be enacted and made known. Note that Ephesians, Philippians and Colossians were written after Acts 28:28, not before it!

Comment: Thanks @ChristianDoulos,  Definitely helped me to sort this passage out.  What threw me for a loop is Paul speaking in a priestly matter in offering up the Gentiles.  Sounds strange to my ears, not being an Israelite. Had to study this out some more to understand what he was saying.  Paul was offering up the Gentiles on behalf of Christ's work that had been given to Paul to turn the Gentiles to God through the gospel.  They too had been made acceptable to God, even as living sacrifices that are a sweet smell to God.  In other words our lives are also a gift to God through Christ.

Comment: This took place when the Gentiles were still under Israel's blessings that were going on at the time.  It's interesting that Paul did it since he was the apostle to the Gentiles because Israel had not yet come accepted her Messiah nationality yet.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no contradiction.

### Logical reading

I would read these two verses as follows:

A) Heb 4.6 -- For those who are fallen, they cannot repent.

B) Is 27.4-5 -- If you do not yield fruit then you will be burned unless you repent.

I don't see a contradiction between these two verses. Take someone with thorns. If they are able to repent, then they are not fallen, they are merely going through testing, which will turn to their benefit and allow them to overcome the world. Both A) and B) are true and they are saved.

If they are not able to repent, then they are fallen, and so again both A) and B) are true and they are burned.

Thus whether or not a person is able to repent is the question, and these verses do not contradict each other as they predict the same outcome in every situation.

### Homiletic reading

Changing tack a bit, this verse in Hebrews is one of the "hard sayings" that makes all of us feel a bit nervous. Another is Mathew's parable of the wedding banquet (Matt 22). Famous heroes of the faith, doctors of the church, have confessed to being terrified at reading this parable.

But the issue here is the definition of "fallen". In normal religious circles, people interpret this to mean taking up smoking, or not attending church, or dating someone not of the faith, committing some crime, etc.  Basically outward things.

It is people who subscribe to this carnal definition of falling away that can't explain why Samson is in the Hebrews Hall of Faith a few chapters past this one.

Hebrews 6 is speaking of things of the spirit, not sensual things, so there is simply no outward act that you can observe which can determine whether or not the person is indeed "fallen" -- the only criteria we know is that *if* they were truly fallen, then they would not be able to repent.

Thus the moment someone *is* repentent, then that *proves* that whatever happened in their past was God's spirit doing the necesssary work within them to overcome the world, just as Samson achieved victory and in that victory became a Hero of the Faith.

Comment: Hi @Robert. To my ears, that sounds like a theological musing rather than an exegetical one. Here, it feels out of place. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @ruminator Asking whether two statements contradict each other is a logical musing. If A and B have the same outcome in every state of the world, they cannot contradict each other. The exegetical part is just reading what A and B are actually saying and then running over the states of the world to see if they disagree.

Comment: Okay, thanks, Robert.

Comment: I agree, Robert. This clearly shows it is NOT speaking to the body of Christ where salvation is totally by God's grace through the faith of Jesus Christ alone -- not of works lest any person should boast. Israel has to 'remain faithful to the end' to be saved; totally contradictory to the Pauline epistles.

Answer (score 0):

There are many instances where the phrases of possibility and ability don't mean in the absolute sense, even in the modern English, like "I cannot commit adultery, I is impossible that I may betray my wife". The sense is not of physical possibility but that I *would not*, implying certainty, imperative and intention. "Would" also indicates certainty or uncertainty. The difference between the nuances of shall and will has also a similar effect where "will" shows certainty.

Since the ancient languages did not contain verbs and adverbs of justification and disclaimer, the modern reader who is used to hear the adverbs like *almost* in every general statement tend to misunderstand them. Thus we have absolutely no general statements in the postmodern language of the modern times. Few examples in English:

- Used with verbs:

"His ideas sound impossible."
(sound, seem, be: is/am/are, appear, look, prove)

"The bad weather made it impossible to play baseball."
(made)

"I find it impossible to stay mad at him."
(find)

"He is impossible to work with."
(be: is/am/are, be + becoming, remains)

- Used with adverbs:

"It is absolutely impossible to finish the project today."
(absolutely, completely, totally, utterly, humanly, downright)

"It is almost impossible to reach him during the day."
(almost, nearly, practically, virtually, simply, pretty)

"Her handwriting is literally impossible to read."
(literally)

"It is physically impossible to achieve that goal."
(physically, technically, scientifically, mathematically, logically)

"You are just impossible to live with."
(just, simply, absolutely, completely, quite, totally)

---

Reading the verses in context helps to understand the sense. The same figurative sense of certainty applies to other verses about not being capable of sinning, or the impossibility of apostates to repent back to God.

- 1 John 3:9: “Whoever is born of God does not commit sin, because his seed remains in him; and he cannot sin (ού δύναται not able to) , because he is born of God.” (NHEB)
- Luke 17:1: “He said to the disciples, “It is impossible that no occasions of stumbling should come, but woe to him through whom they come.”
- Matthew 7:18: “A good tree cannot produce evil fruit, neither can a corrupt tree produce good fruit.”
- Hebrews 6:4: ἀδύνατον (impossible): “For it is impossible in the case of those who have once been enlightened, tasted the heavenly gift, become partakers of the Holy Spirit,” NET

**BDAG3 on αδύνατος**

ⓑ subst. οἱ ἀδύνατοι (Hyperid. 2, 10 contrasted w. δυνάμενοι εἰπεῖν, those who cannot speak; TestJob 45:2 [w. πτωχοί in a gener. sense]) of those weak in faith (opp. οἱ δυνατοί) Ro 15:1.—τὰ ἀδύνατα what is powerless Dg 9:6b.—τὸ ἀδύνατον inability εἰς τὸ τυχεῖν 6a; τὸ καθʼ ἑαυτοὺς ἀδύνατον εἰσελθεῖν our own inability to enter 9:1. Cp. δύναμαι w. neg.

② incapable of happening or being done, impossible (Pind., Hdt. et al.; LXX, Philo, Joseph.; Ar. 5, 2; Just.; Tat. 20, 2; Ath.).

ⓐ adj. ἀ. w. and without ἐστίν (B-D-F §127, 2) it is impossible Hm 11:19ab; παρὰ ἀνθρώποις τοῦτο ἀ. ἐστιν Mt 19:26; Mk 10:27 (cp. Philo, Spec. Leg. 1, 282; Jos., Ant. 10, 196; PCairZen 31, 8 [III b.c.]; dedicatory ins fr. Phrygia in Steinleitner 59, no. 31, 4f: Μητρὶ Λητῷ ὅτι ἐξ ἀδυνάτων δυνατὰ ποιεῖ.—Ps.-Lucian, Halc. 3 ἀδύνατος and δυνατός of that which God cannot and can do); οὐδὲν ἀ. παρὰ τῷ θεῷ 1 Cl 27:2 (cp. Pind., P. 10, 48–50); cp. Lk 18:27. W. inf. foll. and acc. w. the inf. (Wsd 16:15; 2 Macc 4:6; Jos., Ant. 5, 109; Ar., Just., Ath.) Hb 6:4, 18; 10:4; 11:6; Hs 9, 26, 6; MPol 6:1. οὐκ ἔστιν ἀ. ὑπὲρ ὀνόματος θεοῦ (sc. τοῦτο ποιεῖν) IPhld 10:2.

**On δύναμαι**
to possess capability (whether because of personal or external factors) for experiencing or doing someth., can, am able, be capable.

ⓐ w. inf. foll.

α. pres. inf. (Poyaenus 8, 10, 3 φέρειν δύν.) οὐδεὶς δύναται δυσὶ κυρίοις δουλεύειν Mt 6:24; Lk 16:13.—Mt 9:15; 19:12; Mk 2:7, 19 al. καθὼς ἠδύναντο ἀκούειν Mk 4:33 (w. ref. to level of understanding; cp. Epict. 2, 24, 11). Expressed with strong emotion in rejection of what is heard τίς δύναται αὐτοῦ ἀκούειν Who can listen to such talk! (REB) J 6:60. οὐ δ. ἀναστὰς δοῦναί σοι I’m in no position to get up and grant your request Lk 11:7. οὐ δυνάμεθα … μὴ λαλεῖν we cannot remain silent τὶ about someth. Ac 4:20. In questions πῶς δύνασθε ἀγαθὰ λαλεῖν; how can you say good things? Mt 12:34. πῶς δύναται σατανᾶς σατανᾶν ἐκβάλλειν; how can Satan drive out Satan? Mk 3:23; cp. J 6:52; Lk 6:42.

β. aor. inf. (IAndrosIsis, Kyme 4; Just. A I, 2, 4 ἀποκτείναι μὲν δύνασθε, βλάψαι δʼ οὔ; Ath. 15, 1 διακρῖναι οὐ δυνάμενοι) δύνασθαι … εἰσελθεῖν Mk 1:45.—2:4; 5:3; Lk 8:19; 13:11; 14:20 and oft. The impf. ἐδύνατο τοῦτο πραθῆναι this could have been sold Mt 26:9 (B-D-F §358, 1; cp. Wsd 11:19f).

γ. likew. the impf. w. pf. inf. ἀπολελύσθαι ἐδύνατο he could have been set free Ac 26:32.

ⓑ abs., whereby the inf. can easily be supplied (cp. Eur., Or. 889; Thu. 4, 105, 1; X., An. 4, 5, 11 al.; Sir 43:30; Bar 1:6; 1 Macc 6:3; 9:9, 60; 4 Macc 14:17b; ParJer 4:6 cod. C ἠδυνήθητε ἐπʼ αὐτῇ [s. ἰσχύω]; Just., A II, 15, 2 ἵνα εἰ δύναιντο μεταθῶνται ‘in the hope that they might possibly be converted’) Mt 16:3 (sc. διακρίνειν); 20:22b; Mk 10:39 (sc. πιεῖν); 6:19 (sc. ἀποκτεῖναι); cp. Lk 9:40; 16:26; 19:3; Ac 27:39; Ro 8:7. καίπερ δυνάμενος although he was able to do so 1 Cl 16:2. οὔπω γὰρ ἐδύνασθε (sc. χρῆσθαι τῷ βρώματι) you were not yet strong enough (=‘you were not yet up to it’) 1 Cor 3:2. ὑπὲρ ὸ̔ δύνασθε (sc. ἐνεγκεῖν) beyond your capability 10:13.

Comment: Interesting. Something to think about.

Answer (score -1):

My view on Hebrews and on his position regarding saints-turned-sinners is embodied in [this fairly lengthy post elsewhere](https://www.quora.com/Who-wrote-the-book-of-Hebrews/answer/Bill-Ross-22).